# Cannot call start on a completed task

Tags: c#, task

I got this simple code. When click the button DoSomething(),DoSomethingElse() and DoEvenMore() run nicely and i wait for it to finish.

```
void Button1Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   Task one = new Task(() => DoSomething());
   Task two = new Task(() => DoSomethingElse());
   Task three = new Task(() => DoEvenMore());

   one.start();
   two.start();
   three.start();
}

void DoSomething()
{
   label1.Text = "One started";

}

void DoSomethingElse()
{
   label1.Text += "Two started";

}

void DoEvenMore()
{
   label1.Text += "Three started";

}
```

Now if i click the button again without exiting the program i get an InvalidOperationException with the above meessage. What should i do so i can execute the same task each time i click the button without having to exit the program?

Comment: What do those methods do?  None of the code here is calling `Start` on a task, so it won't generate that error.  One of those methods must, in it's body, be calling `Start` on some task.

Comment: fixed now. the exception happens on the first start(); They just print "task one two and three completed" to a label. just to play with tasks no real program

Comment: This is why it's important to post an example capable of replicating the issue you actually have.  Currently this doe will not; you're never starting a task more than once.

Comment: This is exactly my code as it is for learning purposes. If i click once everything is ok. if i click twice i get the exception. i on;y got a label and a button on my form and the code above nothing else.

Comment: That code won't generate the error message you've indicated.  You're *not* calling start on a task that has already completed.  What you are doing is accessing UI elements from a non-UI thread, so you will get an error for that, but it's an entirely different error.  It also won't compile as you haven't spelled `Start` correctly.  Clearly this is not your code.

Comment: Sir i do't know what else to do.. this is my code thank you for your efforts.

Comment: The code won't even *compile* given that you haven't spelled `Start` properly (remember C# is case sensitive) so I *know* that this isn't your exact code.

Comment: i just typed it sir sorry for the small s. anyway thanks again.

Comment: @sparky - Here's what else to do: 1. Copy your code from here and try to compile it. Note that compilation fails. 2. Fix the code so that it will compile and try to reproduce your error. Note that you get a different error message than you posted here. 3. Decide whether you posted the wrong code or the wrong error message. If it was the wrong error message, edit your question to include the correct error message along with code that compiles. Or, if your code is wrong, keep fixing your code until you have an example that demonstrates the problem you are trying to resolve, then post that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me and I can click the button multiple times without throwing the error in your title:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

  void Button1Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
     Task one = new Task(() => DoSomething());
     Task two = new Task(() => DoSomethingElse());
     Task three = new Task(() => DoEvenMore());

     one.Start();
     two.Start();
     three.Start();
  }

  void DoSomething()
  {
     if (InvokeRequired) Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { DoSomething(); });
     else label1.Text = "One started";

  }

  void DoSomethingElse()
  {
     if (InvokeRequired) Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { DoSomethingElse(); });
     else label1.Text += "Two started";

  }

  void DoEvenMore()
  {
     if (InvokeRequired) Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { DoEvenMore(); });
     else label1.Text += "Three started";

  }
   }

}
```

Comment: You can shorten that up a little: `if (InvokeRequired) Invoke((Action)DoSomething);`.  I'd eliminate the conditional statements, and just call `Invoke()` from the Tasks: `new Task(() => Invoke((Action)DoSomething));`

Comment: Yeah, in this case you could.  I like using this syntax because it can be used inside of the same method I wish to run (hence the conditional) regardless of how much code needs to be run inside (which goes in the else).  If I use a Task then I have to put the code in an anonymous method or a separate method.